# How do I calculate the distribution of these two normally distributed random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Say I have $X_1,..., X_n$ whcih are iid Normal Distributions following $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ where $\mu=\sigma$

What would be the distribution of $\sum_1^nX_i -\bar{X}$, and further, what would be the distribution $\sum_1^n (X_i-\bar{X})^2$?

Would I be right in thinking that $X_i$ is $N(\mu,\mu^2)$ and $\bar{X}$ is $N(\mu,\mu^2/n)$ so $X_i+\bar{X}$ is $N(2\mu, (\mu^2(1+n))/n)$?

Or even if that is right, I don't know how to go about working out the distribution when there is a squared involved.

Comment: which two ............?

Comment: See the second line R.E the distribution of $\sum^n_1 X_i - \bar{X}$

Comment: Which two Normally distributed random variables?

Comment: What is $\overline{X}$? I could assume or make a good guess… but still…

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, notation needs to be precise. My best guess is that
$$\bar{X}={1\over n}\sum_{j=1}^n X_j$$ 
If this is the case, $X_i$ and $\bar{X}$ cannot be treated as independent. The first question (assuming the sum is over both terms following):
$$Y=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(X_i-\bar{X}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(X_i-{1\over n}\sum_{j=1}^n X_j\right)=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i-{n\over n}\sum_{j=1}^n X_j=0$$
So $Y$ is not random at all. The second question
$$Z=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(X_i-\bar{X}\right)^2=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(X_i-{1\over n}\sum_{j=1}^n X_j\right)^2=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(X_i^2-{2\over n}X_i\sum_{j=1}^n X_j+{1\over n^2}\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^n X_jX_k\right)$$
Let $U=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2$ and $W=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1}^nX_jX_k$, $j\neq k$.
$$Z=U-{2\over n}U-{2\over n}W+{n\over n^2}U+{n\over n^2}W=\left(1-{1\over n}\right)U-{1\over n}W$$
I am not familiar with the properties of $U$ and $W$ given the form for the $X_i$ that you are considering. One can work out the expectation for $Z$, given that
$$E[U]=\sum_{i=1}^nE[X_i^2]=\sum_{i=1}^nV[X_i]+E[X_i]^2=n(\sigma^2+\mu^2)=2n\mu^2$$
and with $j\neq k$, $V_{jk}=E[X_jX_k]-E[X_j]E[X_k]=0$
$$E[W]=\sum_{j=1}^n\sum_{k=1,k\neq j}^nE[X_jX_k]=(n^2-n)\mu^2$$
so
$$E[Z]={n-1\over n}2n\mu^2-{1\over n}(n^2-n)\mu^2=(n-1)\mu^2$$

Hope this helps.